# How did the author get that $\mathbb{E}(N) = 2$ and $\text{Var}(N) = 2$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

I have the following problem:

> In the country Maxvierk the number $N$ of children of a randomly selected family, and the number $G$ of girls among the children, are given by the following joint probability mass function:
>
> [image]
>
> Determine $\mathbb{E}[N|G = g]$ and $\text{Var}[N|G = g]$.

The solution begins as follows:

> We know already that $\mathbb{E}(N) = 2$ and $\text{Var}(N) = 2$.

How did the author get that $\mathbb{E}(N) = 2$ and $\text{Var}(N) = 2$?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\Bbb E(N)$, notice that the sums across each row are equal to $1/5$. Thus, $N=0,\cdots,4$ are all equally likely. Thus, the average value of $0,\cdots,4$ is the expectation, giving $2$.

More rigorously, consider the definition:

$$\Bbb E(N) = \sum_{N=0}^4 N \cdot \Bbb P(N)$$

Since $\Bbb P(N) = 1/5$ for all $N$ here, since the sums across the rows each are that, we simply end up with $1/5 \sum N$, which is again visibly $2$.

---

For $\text{Var}(N)$, again, a definition:

$$\text{Var}(N) = \underbrace{\sum_{N=0}^4 N^2 \cdot \Bbb P(N)}_{\Bbb E(N^2)} - \underbrace{\left( \sum_{N=0}^4 N \cdot \Bbb P(N) \right)^2}_{\Bbb E(N)^2} =  \frac 1 5 \sum_{N=0}^4 N^2 - 4$$

Taking the sum by your method of your choice gives $6$, so $\text{Var}(N) = 2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Out of curiosity, how does one conclude that $P(N)$ is used in $\sum_{N=0}^4 N^2 \cdot P(N)$, since we actually have $N^2$ in $\mathbb{E}[N^2]$? This is a small detail that sometimes comes up and has been troubling me.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, I just go off the definitions. Sadly, I haven't studied enough probability to understand the motivation for some definitions like that a ton - it's more like muscle memory for me, I suppose you could say? Sorry.

Comment: The expected value definition? The problem is, it's not clear to me what about the definition indicates that we would have $\sum_{N=0}^4 N^2 \cdot P(N)$ rather than $\sum_{N=0}^4 N^2 \cdot P(N^2)$?

Comment: I mean that, I understand that $\Bbb E[X] = \sum X \cdot \Bbb P(X)$, and I know that, if we instead have $\Bbb E[X^2]$, then we calculate it with $\sum X^2 \cdot \Bbb P(X)$, though why that follows doesn't make a ton of sense to me. That's what I'm saying - that I've seen it, and I can use it for rudimentary exercises, though don't necessarily understand why it takes that form. (At least I think that touches on the question I think you're asking. Sorry if I'm totally off-base or just being unclear.)

Comment: Ahh ok, that's fine. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I suppose one argument would be that $\sum N^2 \cdot \Bbb P(N^2)$ doesn't make sense. For example, your $N=4$ term here would yield $\Bbb P(16)$, yet you have no way to guess what that probability is when your data set only concerns $N=0, \cdots, 4$.. Of course that doesn't help a ton  - it only says why $\sum N^2 \cdot \Bbb P(N^2)$ doesn't make sense, but it doesn't justify the form we actually use. Sorry.

Comment: The motivation for the definition of $\mathbb E[X^2]$ (and similar concepts) came up recently as a standalone question. That question may be of some use in this discussion.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395188/computing-the-second-moment-expectation

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$\mathbb{E}(N)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(N\mid G=g)]=\sum_g \mathbb{E}(N\mid G=g)\mathbb{P}(G=g).$$

Also,
$$Var(N)=Var(\mathbb{E}(N\mid G=g))+\mathbb{E}(Var(N\mid G=g)).$$